# Webview crash in ios with PDFJS

Tags: ios, uiwebview, pdf.js

I have loaded a pdf in a `UIWebView` using `PDFJS` [(pdf.js mozilla library)](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/).

All loading is fine, but the app crashes, when the user scrolls very fastly and when zoom. Up on debugging, I noticed that App received memory warning and crashed.

Anyone faced this issue, how do we handle the memory warning generated by UIWebview?

Comment: Crosspost https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/7484